# Visualizing GPS points on interactive map

Tags: python-3, pandas

I am using version 3.0 of python, I want to visualize GPS points in my dataset on interactive map. Is there any python library that can help me to visualize my data on maps.

The input dataset in given in the link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JjvS7igTmrtLA4E5Rs5D6tsdAXqzpYqX/view

Three lines of the dataset:

```
lat,long,tep,ht,altitude,date,time,userid,date_time,Transportation_Mode,time_delta,trip_id,segmentid,Vincenty_distance,velocity,acceleration,jerk
39.97954667,116.3068133,0,0,40784.42587,8/29/2011,10:13:15,141,8/29/2011 10:13,walk,1,1,1,1.551676553,1.551676553,0.550163852,-1.017629555
39.97955833,116.3068233,0,0,40784.42588,8/29/2011,10:13:16,141,8/29/2011 10:13,walk,1,1,1,2.101840405,2.101840405,-0.467465704,0.732307066
```

Comment: Although I'm beginner here but my question was too specific so that I got the right answer by Mr. Kadir, I was looking for some library and tutorials that can serve my purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can visualize your data on a map using **folium**. Please visit [Documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/). (You must also have/install jupyter package. [Installing Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html))

Then this script displays your data on an interactive map:

```
import pandas as pd
import folium

map_ = folium.Map(location=[40.13, 116.25], zoom_start=10)
df = pd.read_csv("PATH/YOUR/FILE/user141.csv") # edit path

locs = df[['lat', 'long']]
loc_list = locs.values.tolist()

# To display all data use the following two lines, but, since your data has
# so many points, this process will be time-consuming.
for point in range(0, len(loc_list)):
    folium.Marker(loc_list[point]).add_to(map_)
    
# To display first 1000 points
# for point in range(0, 1000):
#     folium.Marker(loc_list[point]).add_to(map_)

map_
```

Map for first 1000 points
[image]

Please also review [Mapping Points with Folium](https://georgetsilva.github.io/posts/mapping-points-with-folium).

Comment: It works good for limited set of points, but I need to display all points for analysis purpose. The given data is for one user only, but in actual, total dataset contains more than 100 users and a total number of points exceeds one million.

Comment: It works actually for all points. I just set to display first 1000 points. I edited the code to display all points.

Comment: yes it was working but very slow and didn't display the result even after an hour. Is there any other alternative for that like shape file that can process it quickly?

Answer (score 1):

Simplekml can create a kml file from a Pandas dataframe in four lines:

```
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.Kml()
df.apply(lambda X: kml.newpoint(name=X["name"], coords=[(                                     
X["longitude"],X["latitude"])]) ,axis=1)
kml.save(path = "data.kml")
```

[Link](https://gist.github.com/tdhopper/5247816)

Comment: How can it help me to visualize GPS points?

Comment: The code creates a kml file, that you can view on Google Earth, using a data frame (Pandas) defined in the code as df.